# Why does uWSGI in Docker fail from CMD but run from command line?

Tags: docker, uwsgi, alpine-linux

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add uwsgi
CMD ["/usr/sbin/uwsgi", "--socket 127.0.0.1:8000"]
```

Running it, with `docker run <image name>`, results in the following error:

```
/usr/sbin/uwsgi: unrecognized option: socket 127.0.0.1:8000
getopt_long() error
```

However, running `docker run <image name> /usr/sbin/uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:8000`
works fine. According to [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd), using `CMD` like this "does not invoke a command shell. This means that normal shell processing does not "happen." I am not sure whether this is the culprit.

How do I get uWSGI to work with CMD whilst still using the alpine version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--socket` and `127.0.0.1:8000` is a different options.
You have to specify:

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/uwsgi", "--socket", "127.0.0.1:8000"]
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you. The docs say "[a]ny additional parameters must be individually expressed as strings in the array" so I mistakenly thought that the parameter and its value should go together.